# Dubai - how to manage breakfast when I cannot get from Hotel

Tags: dubai, hotels

Due to family reasons, we are travelling and stopping over in Dubai for 15 days. The challenge is that most hotels in downtown are quite expensive if chosen with breakfast. We're just wondering if anyone knows about how to manage your breakfast (and perhaps some other meals) in Dubai whilst staying in Downtown?

Comment: (serious question) Aren't there  many restaurants all over the place ?

Comment: [It seems so...](https://www.google.co.il/maps/search/Restaurants/@25.1944969,55.2710312,15z/data=!4m8!2m7!3m6!1sRestaurants!2sDowntown+Dubai+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates!3s0x3e5f682f700cf983:0xb5cc58b076c0b904!4m2!1d55.2784141!2d25.1949849?hl=en)

Comment: Are you asking about finding stores or markets for make-your-own meals? What have you done to search for them?

Comment: We weren't there for as long and just went to restaurants and shopping centres. Downtown does have the Dubai Mall, which should have everything you need.

Comment: If you're staying for two weeks, why not get a serviced apartment and cook yourself?

Comment: Some of this depends a bit on what you consider to be a suitable breakfast. A cup of coffee and a pastry from a coffee shop might work for some people, juice, yogurt and piece of fruit you bought at the store and keep in the fridge in your hotel room could work for others, while some might be looking for a restaurant that does full meals with eggs and breakfast meats.

Comment: Have you considered renting a short-term apartment?

Comment: Full breakfasts in restaurants seem to run around $10 USD per person and up. If that's too much maybe consider cooking some or all of the time.  That said I see cheap hotels with (probably mediocre) buffet breakfast as cheap as $10 USD for two.